# Getting 401 error on XHR request from local frontend app to local backend Sails JS Blueprint REST route

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have a frontend Vue app running on localhost:8080. I'm attempting to send a request to my backend application, a Sails JS node app, running on localhost:1337.

My request code from my Vue app looks like this:

**actions/index.vue**

```
async testFetch() {
  await fetch('http://localhost:1337/recipe', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        displayName: 'test',
      }),
    });
}
```

According to Chrome devtools, the request appears to be sending properly. Copied as CURL:

```
curl 'http://localhost:1337/recipe' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Origin: http://localhost:8080' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
  -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8080/' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  --data-binary '{"displayName":"test"}' \
  --compressed
```

My backend app is a Sails JS node app that was created with Sails JS CLI version `1.4.0`. I ran the command `sails new` and chose the `webapp` option. I run the app with `sails lift`.

I believe I have the proper CORS settings for the Sails app. In any case, before I set up CORS setttings, I was getting CORS errors on the frontend, and now I'm not.

**backend/config/security.js**

```
module.exports.security = {
  cors: {
    allRoutes: true,
    allowOrigins: ['http://localhost:8080'],
  },
  csrf: false
};
```

I have disabled csrf for now so as to reduce variables in debugging.

According to the [Sails JS documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/blueprints/blueprint-routes), if I have enable REST Blueprints, then when I create a Model, there should automatically be routes and actions created for it (if the server is torn down and re-launched with `sails lift`). I believe I have the proper configuration to enable this feature:

**backend/config/blueprints.js**

```
module.exports.blueprints = {
  actions: false,
  rest: true,
  shortcuts: false,
};
```

I believe I have established a Model properly, so Sails should be creating a Blueprint Route and Blueprint Action for said model:

**backend/api/models/Recipe.js**

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    displayName: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      example: 'Mamas puddin',
    },
  },
};
```

As far as I'm aware, I have no conflicting actions or controllers in `backend/api/controllers`. Also, as far as I'm aware, I have no conflicting routes in `backend/config/routes.js`. My response as viewed in Chrome devtools is "Unauthorized," with a status code of `401`. The terminal running `sails lift` shows `<- POST /recipe`. If I send a request to a different route, say, `/foo/bar`, I get a 404. Also, if I navigate my browser to localhost:1337 (rather than simply use the Sails JS app as an API), the default Sails JS webapp functions properly.

**How can I send an XHR request to a Blueprint route on a Sails JS app?**

Comment: Allowed origins, doesnt have localhost:1337 listed

Comment: Allowed origins under the Sails JS config? The sails JS server is hosted under the :1337 port, but I shall try adding it just to see.

Comment: I added :1337 to the allowOrigins array, and still have the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I was getting 401 is that the default Sails webapp has a policy applied to all routes that requires them to be logged in (the login middleware is run on every route), with a few exceptions.

In order to use my Blueprint route, I needed to add an exception to this policy for my *action. (EDIT: I believe the policies map to *actions* rather than routes.)

**backend/config/policies.js**

```
module.exports.policies = {

  '*': 'is-logged-in',

  // Bypass the `is-logged-in` policy for:
  'entrance/*': true,
  'account/logout': true,
  'view-homepage-or-redirect': true,
  'view-faq': true,
  'view-contact': true,
  'legal/view-terms': true,
  'legal/view-privacy': true,
  'deliver-contact-form-message': true,
  // I needed to add my Model's Blueprint route to the exceptions
  'recipe/*': true,

};
```

I believe `true` simply takes place of a possible policy function. In any case, the request now succeeds with a `200` code.